# hello all does anyone of you know a function in jena to split( other than split function) a URI string

Tags: jena

For example for a string like :
"https://www.example.com/myname:abcd"

I want only the part before ":"
i.e i want an output as below:
"https://www.example.com/myname"

Comment: You want to split, but not using the split function?

Comment: yeah i have read on a trustworthy source that there is some function in jena to do that . do you have any idea regarding that??? because what I am doing is extracting the object using statement and in the output i just want the URI part "https://www.example.com/myname" and not https://www.example.com/myname:abcd"

Comment: I think it's important to note that in your example, you're asking for the part before the **second** ":".   I would have said that you could parse the uri and then ask for the scheme to get "https".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is to extract the namespace of the resource.

`resource.getNamespace()` will do the trick ;)

Comment: Thanks I was looking for  something like this :) It worked !

Comment: You're welcome :)
And btw, from the comments I have read here, I think you are misunderstanding what _URI_ means. _URI_ stands for Unique Resource Indentifier, therefor `https://www.example.com/myname:abcd` is the uri of a resource. Such uri is compounded by the **namespace** the resource 'belongs to' and the **local name** it has in said namespace.

Answer (score 0):

In SPARQL:

```
REPLACE("https://www.example.com/myname:abcd", ":[^:]*$", "")
```

In code, use a plain java string operation.